# How do I make div background image show accross top of webpage?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am working on making a navigation bar, and I am running into a problem. This is what my navigation bar looks like:

[image]

It has like a 8px white border around it, and this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Without the 8px white border around it.

I am using this code for it:

```
.header
{
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background : #464646;
background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(168,168,168)), to(rgb(69,69,69)));
background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(168,168,168), rgb(69,69,69));
border-top:1px solid #939393;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

I can using this:

```
margin-left:-8px;
margin-right:-8px;
margin-top:-8px;
```

And put width to 102%, but then it gives me scrollbars on the bottom.

This may be confusing, but I am a beginner, and I need help.
If you can help me, I will appreciate it a lot!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gwM4X/) Take the margin off the body if you do mean like this.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks. Post that as an answer!

Comment: @Ruddy please put answers in the answer field so it can be voted on. Thank you

Comment: Thank you to all who helped me. That has fixed a problem I have been trying to get to work for hours! I should have thought about StackOverFlow and asked earlier!

Comment: @edno70 That's why `SO` is here! If you get stuck just come ask a question like you did and someone will help.

Comment: Yeah, I got 5 answers in about 1 1/2 minutes!

Comment: A quick question, does anyone know how to make it only put the padding into the navigation bar area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the margin on your body to 0 like this:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `body` tag comes with margins. That is your problem.

Do:

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

User Agents apply default styles to your web page, which you need to override, in this case it's `margin` so either you can reset the `margin` like

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Else you can also use a `*` universal selector like

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gwM4X/)

---

For a proper stylesheet reset, use [CSS RESET STYLESHEET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is due to the `user agent stylesheet` - effectively the browser default styling.

Comment: I only want it in the navigation bar, and not the whole page.

Comment: There was no margin on the nav bar. Its was the body.

Comment: No no, you dont understand. By default the body has a margin. Thats why your nav was off the top of the page. The div that is your nav does not have a margin unless you set it. The problem was the body had a margin not the nav, the only way the nav would have had a margin (or padding) is if you set it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because the browser has some default styling, one of which is a margin of 8px surrounding the content, look into "css reset" or if you just want to remove that one thing try

```
body
{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

set your html and body to:

```
   body, html {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

This will reset all browsers and remove the border.

Answer (score 2):

This will declare on the entire page not just to the Body.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/gwM4X/2/

Comment: The thing is, I only want it done in the navigation bar.

Comment: Its a common reset that removes un used whitespace found around headers, navs etc. This a general use code found on almost all websites.

Comment: Ok. I'll have to remember that then.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Here is an awesome guide to that will help you in the future, im always learning something new hear. http://www.cssreset.com/